# Allow Self Signed Certificate on iOS for Downloads

Tags: ios, flutter, ssl

I have a Flutter app that downloads files from a server that uses a self-signed certificate.

As an Android developer, this is not a problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">subdomain.domain.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/iotccpem" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

But if I now run this app on iOS, of course it doesn't work.

I have read various things about this and ended up here. I don't have that much experience developing for iOS.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false />
    <key>NSPinnedDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>subdomain.domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPinnedCAIdentities</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>SPKI-SHA256-BASE64</key>
                    <string>+V2Jp3+Q27t23D7amlWpiIFQfx0TivlE6MjvpR7iLC4=</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I have generated the Base64 string with

```
cat iotccpem | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -outform pem -pubkey | openssl pkey -pubin -inform pem -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Unfortunately, I still can't establish an SSL connection, but only receive the error that no SSL connection could be established.

I might be able to install some certificates on the device, but this is not an option.

I probably won't be able to use a `badCertificateCallback` or something like that because I don't know what the Flutter Library [Background Downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/background_downloader) uses internally and I don't have access to it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Apologies in advance if you've already considered and rejected it for some reason, but you could avoid having a self-signed certificate by getting a real one, for free, from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), which would bypass the problem... (Depending on where you're hosting the files, they may have an integration with LE to make getting one really easy.)